# Automating PayPal refunds, is it a trouble?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

Our business is going to accept recurring payments from customers through PayPal.

There is no way to prevent a customer to subscribe to our service twice, by creating two PayPal subscription or recurring payments. But this makes no sense to pay for our service more than once.

Should we issue a refund *automatically* if somebody subscribes more than once?

I am afraid that making this system automated may open a door for trolls and unjust competitors. Someone may (however this may cost them some money) intentionally create duplicate PayPal subscriptions and automatically receive many refunds from us.

I am concerned with two issues about automatic issuing many refunds:

- Will PayPal tolerate us, if we this way issue refunds too often?
- How much it may cost to us to make refunds? I am not sure if refunds are done entirely at the expense of PayPal or will it cost to use more than we receive from the refunded payment, thus creating a negative profit? I don't know, please explain.

If making it simply automated this way isn't good, please explain a good way to do it. For example, is it a good idea to allow such automatic refunds but no more than 5 times per month? Any other good strategy?

Note that we consider to make a full featured payment engine for use by other companies in some future.

Comment: PayPal has the option to block payments with the same invoice ID. It seems that I need just add invoice ID and block duplicate invoices, right?

Comment: When issuing a refund, from what I see, the payer gets the full amount, the merchant gets the amount minus the fee, in my case 2.9%. So yes, you'll end up with a negative balance, so you don't want to do this often. As for using invoiceID to avoid dup subs, I guess it should work, but you will need to identify the buyer in order to generate the same invoiceID given the same buyer and same subscription.